# Serve /wc-api/ thru http instead of https NGINX

Tags: wordpress, http, nginx, https, http-status-code-404

I'm facing an issue, an API needs to use http to run properly on my site and I'm forcing all my traffic to use HTTPS.
I've done some modifications but still can't make it work.
Before adding the redirect on /wc-api/, when I used curl http:// site .com/wc-api/v3 (the url that needs to use http to work) I always got 301 moved permanently; but now with the changes, I'm getting a 404 not found error, so there's something missing. 
Your help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Here's my nginx config:

```
    fastcgi_cache_path /var/run/nginx-cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=WORDPRESS:100m inactive=60m;
    fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
    fastcgi_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_500;
    fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
    server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name site.com www.site.com;
    location / {
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
    location /wc-api/ {
    }
    }
    server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    client_max_body_size 256M;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html;

    server_name site.com www.site.com;

    # this must be near the top to ensure auto-renewals work
    location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
    }

    set $skip_cache 0;

    if ($request_method = POST) {
            set $skip_cache 1;
    }

    if ($query_string != "") {
            set $skip_cache 1;
    if ($request_uri ~* "/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|sitemap(_index)?.xml") {
            set $skip_cache 1;
    }

    if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_no_cache|wordpress_logged_in") {
            set $skip_cache 1;
    }

    autoindex off;

    location ~ /purge(/.*) {
            fastcgi_cache_purge WORDPRESS "$scheme$request_method$host$1";
    }
    location ~* ^.+\.(flv|pdf|avi|mov|mp3|wmv|m4v|webm|aac|ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|css|rss|atom|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|ex$
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location /wc-api/ {
            return 301 http://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_cache_bypass $skip_cache;
            fastcgi_no_cache $skip_cache;
            fastcgi_cache WORDPRESS;
            fastcgi_cache_valid 60m;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
    location ~* ^/wp-includes/.*(?<!(js/tinymce/wp-tinymce))\.php$ {
            internal;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
            access_log off;
            log_not_found off;
    }

    location = /wp-config.php {
            deny all;
    }

    location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
            deny all;
    location ~* ^/wp-content/.*\.(txt|md|exe|sh|bak|inc|php|pot|po|mo|log|sql)$ {
            deny all;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
    }
```

Comment: tried changing 
location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
to 
location / {
}
Inside the 443 server but nothing happened

Comment: You have no `root` directive in your first `server` block.

Comment: Hi! I kept getting the 404 issue, 
2017/03/20 16:51:44 [error] 5138#5138: *10 open() "/var/www/html/wc-api/v3" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: [], server: site.com, request: "GET /wc-api/v3 HTTP/1.1", host: "site.com"
IS there a way to call root or something site.com/wc-api ??